# Error when testing the contract

Tags: truffle, ethereumjs, truffle-test, solidity-0.5.x

**ApprovalContract.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

    contract ApprovalContract{
    address public sender;
    address payable public reciever;
    address public constant approver=0xe05cE3f89b5Ab28d6d2Ac8A503473Cd5A23e616a;

    function deposit (address payable _receiver)external payable{

        require (msg.value > 0);
        sender=msg.sender;
        reciever=_receiver;
    }

    function viewApprover () external pure returns(address) {
        return approver;
    }

    function approve () external payable {

        require (msg.sender==approver);
        reciever.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
    }
```

**2_deploy_contract.js**

```
const ApprovalContract = artifacts.require("ApprovalContract");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(ApprovalContract);
}
```

**For testing, ApprovalContract.js**

```
const ApprovalContract = artifacts.require('ApprovalContract');

console.log("something");
  contract('ApprovalContract', function(accounts) {

    it('initiates contract', async function() {

      const contract = await ApprovalContract.deployed();
      const approver = await contract.approver.call();
      assert.equal(approver, 0x0feeede47d471276377ed83e3ef749995fc0ebe2, "approvers don't match");
    });
    it('takes a deposit', async function () {
      const contract = await ApprovalContract.deployed();
      await contract.deposit(accounts[0], { value: 1e+18, from: accounts[1] });
      assert.equal(web3.eth.getBalance(contract.address), 1e+18, "amount did not match");
    });
    it('makes the transaction when approved, approver: ' + accounts[2], async function () {
      const contract = await ApprovalContract.deployed();
      await contract.deposit(accounts[0], { value: 1e+18, from: accounts[1] });
      await contract.approve({ from: accounts[2] });
      assert.equal(web3.eth.getBalance(contract.address), 0, "didn't transfer ether");
    });
});
```

**truffle compile,truffle migrate run successfully. When I do truffle test,this error comes-**

```
1) Contract: ApprovalContract
   takes a deposit:
 AssertionError: amount did not match: expected {} to equal 1000000000000000000
  at Context.<anonymous> (test/ApprovalContract.js:15:14)
  at <anonymous>
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
```

2) Contract: ApprovalContract

```
makes the transaction when approved, approver: 0xAD90b2dd2A7E8091349A96e50c4112E1EA0159fE:
 Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
  at Object.ErrorResponse (/home/neha/.nvm/versions/node/v8.16.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3-core-requestmanager/~/web3-core-helpers/src/errors.js:29:1)
```

Comment: Should be `await contract.approver().call()` (parenthesis after the `approver`).

Comment: And choose a different variable name for `contract`. This symbol is already in use by the Truffle testing infrastructure (you can see it appearing at the top of your test file).

Comment: You don't need to specify a file path for `artifacts.require`, just the contract's name (and note that, for example, if the contract inside `ApprovalContract.sol` is **not** named `ApprovalContract`, then your require statement will fail to find it).

Comment: `0xe05cE3f89b5Ab28d6d2Ac8A503473Cd5A23e616` is larger than javascript's `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. Use `"0xe05cE3f89b5Ab28d6d2Ac8A503473Cd5A23e616"` instead (also because `approver().call()` will return a string anyway, so you may as well compare a string with a string).

Comment: Debug your code and find which line causes the error. You can do this by adding a `console.log` before and after every line in your test file.

Comment: I have made the changes in ApprovalContract.js. And posted it again in the question @goodvibration. I am still getting the same error

Comment: You don't need the `.sol` either. Like I said - contract name, not file name. And all of my comments expect for the last one (which you seem to have ignored!), are just minor corrections. Of course they would not solve the Invalid Opcode issue. Please read my last comment and provide the information.

Comment: I edited the .sol. Sorry, if you felt that I ignored your last comment. I dont know how will I check in the browser. I tried it an online js editor and there are no syntax errors. @goodvibration

Comment: What do you mean "check in the browser"? Are you running `truffle test` in a browser? I sincerely doubt that! In your test file, you have an `it` structure, right? Inside that `it`, add a printout - `console.log(something)` - to help you detect when the error exactly takes place.

Comment: I added but it is showing the same error no changes @goodvibration

Comment: So what, you expect a couple of `console.log` to solve the problem? Honestly, the point is for you to be able to tell us exactly which line in your code emits this error! If you are having problems understanding this very basic debug-method, then I suggest that you take some time to learn a couple of those basic concepts / methodologies. You're gonna have a lot more problems ahead otherwise.

Comment: I have made some changes and also specified which line is creating error. Any help would be appreciated@goodvibration

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems in your code:

1. `getBalance` is async. For it to work you need to wait for the result:

   ```
   const balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(contract.address);
   ```
2. Js does not have large numbers so web3 wraps them in a BN object. To compare with other numbers is better to compare them as strings since equal do not understand how to compare BN objects and numbers:

   ```
   assert.equal(
       balance.toString(),
       web3.utils.toBN(1e+18).toString(),
       "amount did not match"
   );
   ```